# Como desenvolver duas versões de um mesmo aplicativo, sendo uma gratuita e a outra paga?

Tags: java, android, google-play

Estou iniciando o desenvolvimento de um aplicativo para Android utilizando o Android Studio, pretendo disponibilizá-lo em duas versões, uma paga, com mais funcionalidades, e uma gratuita, mais básica.

Pensei em começar a desenvolver e após finalizar a versão base, comum entre o aplicativo pago e o gratuito, criar uma cópia do projeto e começar a adicionar novas funcionalidades ao  aplicativo pago, porém não achei essa prática legal, pois existiria informações redundantes (classes, imagens, *layouts*, etc) e sempre que eu encontrar um erro teria que arrumar nos dois projetos, caso o mesmo esteja na versão base.

Gostaria de saber o que fazer nesses casos e se existe algum padrão/ferramenta para lidar com isso.

> **Nota:** versão base são os elementos em comum entre a versão paga e a gratuita, isso inclui as classes, imagens, *layouts* e tudo mais.

Comment: Java, né? Foi uma "ótima" decisão não ter compilação condicional na linguagem. Não é a única técnica mas facilitaria muito. Mas você já quase respondeu. Você teria três projetos. Common, Free, Pay. Os dois últimos devem ser mínimos, principalmente o Free que é só uma cola mesmo. Não respondo oficialmente por que não saberia dar detalhes no caso específico.

Comment: Sim, em Java, não coloquei pois achei que seria desnecessário. Realmente cheguei a pensar no que você disse enquanto estava escrevendo a pergunta, porém como seu novo com o Android Studio, achei que poderia existir uma opção, já que esse tipo de divisão ocorre muito nos aplicativos.

Comment: Tem inúmeras opções mas como não conheço bem a tecnologia vou me abster de indicar algumas. Tem até algumas muito loucas, mas por incrível que pareça adotadas por vários desenvolvedores.

Comment: Ok, mas seu primeiro comentário já deu um caminho, obrigado!

Comment: Mateus, está usando o Android Studio para desenvolver seu projeto? Digo isso porque o Gradle (que é usado como ferramenta de build do Android Studio) possui uma forma de se fazer isso muito fácil. Estou elaborando uma resposta com os detalhes envolvidos.

Comment: Sim @Wakim, Android Studio!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Existe um padrão (não um *Design Pattern* em si) próprio do Android/Gradle para lidar com isso. O pré-requisito seria usar o Android Studio e compilar seu apk usando o Gradle. Pois é o Gradle que fornece essa funcionalidade.

Para lidar com a geração de dois apk's diferentes, o Gradle permite definir **Build/Product Flavors**.

Assim como **Build Types** (release ou debug), **Build/Product Flavors** são, como o próprio nome diz, **"sabores"** (de funcionalidades/código, recursos, configurações e etc...) que seu aplicativo pode ter. As mais comuns são: *Free*, *Paid*, *Phone* e *Tablet* (sendo esses dois últimos desnecessários dependendo do tipo de customização que irá fazer). Você pode dar o nome que quiser para um *flavor*, não tem limitação.

**Correção**: A combinação de um *Build Type* com um *Build Flavor* gera um *Build Variant*. Que seria usado na compilação de fato (isso eu explico melhor no final).

E usando o Gradle é possível gerar um apk por cada combinação de *flavor* e *build type* disponível. Mais abaixo explico como fazer isso:

## Configuração de Build

Uma configuração simples do seu arquivo `build.gradle` seria:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "br.com.testegradleflavors"
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    productFlavors {
        free {
            applicationId "be.tamere.testegradleflavors.free"
        }

        paid {
            applicationId "br.com.testegradleflavors"
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
}
```

Nesse exemplo, eu defino dois **flavors**: *free* e *paid*. Como o *Google Play* obriga, cada apk precisa ter um ID único. Logo cada *flavor* precisa ter um `applicationId` diferente porque no final irá gerar um apk diferente.

Não é preciso e nem **recomendado** mudar a estrutura dos pacotes para ficarem iguais ao `applicationId` de cada *flavor*. Isso porque o Gradle consegue tratar o "merge" dos arquivos do *Build Variant* atual.

É claro que pode tornar essa configuração mais rebuscada, como variáveis de Build:

```
productFlavors {
        free {
            applicationId "be.tamere.testegradleflavors.free"
            buildConfigField "String", "VARIAVEL_ESTATICA", "\"free\""
        }

        paid {
            applicationId "br.com.testegradleflavors"
            buildConfigField "String", "VARIAVEL_ESTATICA", "\"pago\""
        }
    }
```

Existem outras configurações, como até **Multi-flavor Variants** que seriam **Flavors** de múltiplos níveis, mas isso foge muito do escopo da pergunta.

Para acessar essas variáveis de Build no código Java:

```java
String variavel = BuildConfig.VARIAVEL_ESTATICA;
```

---

## Configuração de código/resources

Com relação a código, basta seguir esta estrutura de projeto (seguindo o padrão do gradle):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Nessa imagem, ilustra meu projeto que possui três pastas no mesmo nível hierárquico: *main* com o código/resources comum a todos os *Build Variants* possíveis do aplicativo (padrão em um projeto Gradle criado atualmente), *paid* com as classes/resources/arquivos que é específicos para o apk pago e o *free* com o classes/resources/arquivos específicos para o apk grátis.

Quando você modifica o **Build Variants** (escolhendo um *flavor* diferente), ele desativa visualmente as pastas que não estão sendo usadas. Na imagem por exemplo aparece a `MainActivity` com um símbolo vermelho de erro na pasta free, mas isso é porque a pasta foi desativada quando escolhi o *flavor* **paid**. Quando modificar o *flavor* para free, o inverso irá ocorrer.

É bom não usar o mesmo nome de recursos (classes, xmls, arquivos em geral) entre *main* e *free*/*paid*. Porque os recursos dos pacotes mais específicos (free e paid) irão sobreescrever os recursos do menos específico (main).

Quando um *flavor* é escolhido para o build, ele irá considerar todas as classes e os resources e irá juntar tudo num mesmo apk, sobreescrevendo o que tiver repetido (dando prioridade ao *flavor*). Os arquivos que existem no *main* mas que não existem nos *flavors*, serão incluídos sem problema no apk.

Na hora de fazer o build, basta escolher o *flavor* e o *type*. Isso pode tanto ser por linha de comando:

```
gradlew assembleFreeRelease -- Build para o apk Free em modo Release
gradlew assemblePaidRelease -- Build para o apk Pago em modo Release

gradlew assembleFreeDebug -- Build para o apk Free em modo Debug

-- Demais configurações de build flavor e type
```

Quanto por Interface gráfica: dentro do Android Studio, basta trocar a opção do combobox de **Build Variants** como na imagem da organização do projeto.

## Referências para melhor aprofundamento:

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LCJAgPkpmR0
- http://tulipemoutarde.be/2013/10/06/gradle-build-variants-for-your-android-project.html
- http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Product-flavors
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16737006/using-build-flavors-structuring-source-folders-and-build-gradle-correctly

Comment: Fantástico, impressionante como algo simples pode ser tão útil, só fiquei com uma duvida, quando você diz que cada *flavor* tem que ter um pacote diferente, você está se referindo ao `applicationId` ou a estrutura dos arquivos na pasta java?

Comment: Mateus, você está correto, a estrutura do pacote não muda. Apenas o `applicationId` varia. Outra coisa que misturei foi `build variants` e `build type`. Vou corrigir isso na resposta.