# Como oferecer aplicativo Android grátis e pago no Google Play?

Tags: android, google-play

É meu primeiro aplicativo e não achei a resposta em lugar nenhum.

O aplicativo está pronto pra distribuição no Google Play. Tem duas versões: grátis (com anúncios) e paga (sem anúncios).

Criei o `app` no `Developer Console` e iniciei um teste beta fechado.

Eu pensei que iria upar as duas versões (grátis e pagas) e que a loja iria cuidar das coisas pra trocar a versão quando o usuário faz o pagamento.

Mas o console não permite subir as duas versões.

Por isso a pergunta: como oferecer um `app` com versões grátis e pagas?

Comment: Na verdade, o que as empresas fazem é lançar 2 aplicativos mesmo. Um com propaganda e o outro sem propaganda porém com um determinado valor. Tem que tomar cuidado na questão de que uma vez lançado sendo free, não tem como lançar ele novamente com um valor específico.

Comment: Complementando o comentário, você pode gerar dois apps com id's diferentes e com base no mesmo código mas com funcionalidades diferentes se for o caso. Pra isso você precisa configurar os flavors, da pra fazer muita coisa. Recomendo dar uma olhada nessa minha [resposta sobre flavors](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/46422/como-desenvolver-duas-vers%C3%B5es-de-um-mesmo-aplicativo-sendo-uma-gratuita-e-a-out/46426#46426)

Comment: utilize `flavors` para isso. Melhor meio de realizar o que deseja.

Answer (score -2):

Havia imaginado que subiria as duas versões para o mesmo APP no Console e o Play cuidaria de trocar uma versão pela outra, quando o usuário fizesse a compra.

Depois de ler os comentários e fuçar mais um pouco, entendi que as versões grátis e paga (ou qualquer variação que resulte mais de um APK), são consideradas dois `apps` distintos, mesmo a diferença seja apenas a presença de banners (na versão grátis).

Sendo assim, a resposta correta é:

Para oferecer aplicativos grátis e pagos no Google Play, é preciso criar uma entrada para cada um e tratar cada app individualmente, no console.

Comment: Tem um mecanismo correto para isto https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants (conforme [já comentado na pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/186535/como-oferecer-aplicativo-android-gr%c3%a1tis-e-pago-no-google-play#comment595002_186535) pelo colega LMaker).

Answer (score -3):

Com esta prática que parece ser comum de subir dois aplicativos (um versão grátis e outro versão paga) o usuário teria o desconforto de ter dois app em seu dispositivo ocupando espaço na memória, a menos que ele não confunda os ícones gêmeos e desinstale o primeiro.

O ideal seria que após o pagamento houvessem uma atualização automática onde uma quantidade necessária de arquivos do desenvolvedor tornassem o app versão bloqueada ou com anúncio em versão desbloqueada e sem anúncio.